# Tap Gesture Recognizer is inhibiting touch events on UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uigesturerecognizer, swift4

I've set up `TapGuestureRecognizer` within my `ViewDidLoad()` to dismiss keyboard. My implementation as follows

```
class AddRegistrationTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, SelectRoomTableViewControllerDelegate { 
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    emailAddressTextField.delegate = self
    ...
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:     #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}
...
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    emailAddressTextField.endEditing(true)
}
```

So far so good, this works in dismissing the text field.

But within the Table View Controller, I also have a segue linked up to a cell - which isn't registering the tap (because of the gesture recognizer) to follow through with the segue. I'll need to use 2 fingers to tap on the cell for the segue to be performed. And I've tried removing my above implementation of addGestureRecognizer in the code, and the segue performed as per expectation.

So this led me to believe that the gesture recogniser is inhibiting touch events from registering. Any workarounds or solution that I can implement?

Comment: If the goal is to dismiss the keyboard when done editing, why not configure the Return key in the keyboard to do that, as usual?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dismiss the keyboard why aren't you using the `UITableViewDelegate`method instead of `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      emailAddressTextField.endEditing(true)
}
```

one more thing, the table view is getting the tap gesture and not cell, thats why the segues are not called.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tap to dismiss, implement scroll to dismiss by setting the table view's `keyboardDismissMode` to `.onDrag`. Have your interface work *with* the framework, not against it.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for this would be implementing the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate:

```
class AddRegistrationTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, SelectRoomTableViewControllerDelegate { 
    ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    emailAddressTextField.delegate = self
    ...
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self // You set the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate here
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}
...
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    emailAddressTextField.endEditing(true)
}

// In this UIGestureRecognizerDelegate's method we will check if the text field is actually being edited 
// and if it's not the case, we will cancel this touch for the gesture
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    return emailAddressTextField.isEditing
}
```